# android app to show notification when battery level is above certain percent

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, batterymanager

I want my android app to show notification when the battery level is above certain percentage which is similar to low battery notification in android. Not by assigning a background task which keeps checking battery level in background between every minute. I Just want to trigger notification when battery level is above certain percent even if the app is not running. Can I do this using broadcast receiver? any suggestions?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring

Comment: You can get the battery percent as mentioned above and then fire your own receiver and show a notification inside `onReceive` of the `BroadcastReceiver`

Answer (score 0):

**Broadcast Receiver class**

```
class BatteryBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
     override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent?) {
        val level: Int = intent!!.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0)
        Timber.d("battery - level: %d", level)

    }
}
```

**In Activity/Fragment** register your broadcast

```
val batteryLevel = BatteryBroadcastReceiver();
registerReceiver(batteryLevel, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW));
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, But there is a mistake in your answer  <code>registerReceiver(batteryLevel,  IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)); </code>is correct instead of <code> registerReceiver(batteryLevel, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW));. </code>.But this also works when app is running and do not works when the app is closed. I want to get notification even if the app is closed

Comment: I think it's related with the changes from SDK 26 where implicit broadcasts are no longer allowed excepts for certain types of broadcasts. [Here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts) in offical doc

Comment: Yes but this can be done using foreground service

Comment: Yes, you can use the foreground service.